# std::shared_ptr custom reference counter

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I'm currently working on a code where I'll need to statically share an instance of an object between multiple parts of my code. So basically a singleton. This instance will be shared until no one uses it anymore. At this point I need to perform some cleanup operation before deleting the actual instance.

If someone asks for the shared instance after this point, it will get a newly created one and so on.

So I wrote something like this:

```
template<typename F>
struct static_filter
{
  template<typename ...Args>
  static std::shared_ptr<F> get(Args... a)
  {
    return _inst = _inst ?: std::shared_ptr<F>(new F(a...));
  }

  static void cleanup()
  {
    // some cleanup operation over inst
    _inst.reset();
  }

private:
  static std::shared_ptr<F> _inst;
};

template<typename F> std::shared_ptr<F> static_filter<F>::_inst{nullptr};
```

And now I'm looking in a way to automatically detect when nobody is using _inst anymore.
Basically, I'd like to get a callback each time the use_count() of _inst falls to 1. At this point I would be able to cleanup & reset.

I'd like to avoid implementing my own reference counting for this (the application is using shared_ptr everywhere and it will be kinda tiresome to change to a custom type).

I tried using a custom deleter on my instance, something along the lines of:

```
template<typename F>
struct static_filter
{
  template<typename ...Args>
  static std::shared_ptr<F> get(Args... a)
  {
    return _inst = _inst ?: std::shared_ptr<F>(new F(a..., **static_filter<F>::cleanup**));
  }

  static void cleanup()
  {
    // some cleanup operation over inst
    _inst.reset();
  }

private:
  static std::shared_ptr<F> _inst;
};

template<typename F> std::shared_ptr<F> static_filter<F>::_inst{nullptr};
```

But obviously this did not work as my ref counter never did actually reach 0.

Does anyone knows if there is a way to achieve this using shared_ptr ?

Thanks.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/use_count

Comment: I'm aware of this, I'm looking for a way to be notified when the actual value reaches 1.

The goal here is not having to call cleanup() manually and instead it being triggered as soon as no other part of the code holds a reference to _inst.

Comment: Make `_inst` a weak pointer instead of a shared pointer. `get()` does a `_inst.lock()` and if the lock fails, then it creates a new one. F's destructor is your `cleanup`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `shared_ptr` here is wrong on a semantic level. You do not want to hold ownership in this `static` variable but only observe through it. This is the use case for [`std::weak_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr). With this a static variable you can observe the object, return it as a `shared_ptr` if it exists and do not interefere with its destruction, when others hold a reference to it.

This would look as follows:

```cpp
template<typename F>
struct static_filter
{
  template<typename ...Args>
  static std::shared_ptr<F> get(Args... a)
  {
    // Returns the shared_ptr observed, if it exists and is not expired, empty ptr otherwise
    // is atomic
    auto shared = _inst.lock(); 
    if(!shared) {
        _inst = (shared = std::shared_ptr<F>(new F(a..., **static_filter<F>::cleanup**));
    }
    return shared;
  }

  static void cleanup()
  {
    // Always check if the calling object is really the managed object
    // some cleanup operation over inst
    _inst.reset();
  }

private:
  static std::weak_ptr<F> _inst;
};

template<typename F> std::weak_ptr<F> static_filter<F>::_inst{};
```

Note that this is *not* thread safe (your code before was not thread safe, either), since two simultaneous calls to `get` when the pointer is empty, can both see that the pointer is empty and both construct a new object of type `F`. You will have to add an `std::lock_guard` to avoid this.

Note that even if you could add a callback on `use_count == 1`, this would be inherently unsafe. This is why `std::shared_ptr::unique()` is deprecated from C++17 onwards and is removed in C++20 (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/use_count) and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/unique))

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. And your right, my use of shared_ptr here was invalid.
Thanks a lot for your help :)